# Splitting Field, irreducibility and degree n!

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

> Let $f ∈ F[x]$ have degree $n > 0$, and let $L$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $F$. I wish to show if $[L : F] = n!$ then $f$ is irreducible over $F$.

> Also, the converse of this is false with some counterexample?

I know $[L:F]$ divides $n!$ from this result but i can't make the same method work to prove this~
[Let $K$ be a field and $f(x)\in K[X]$ be a polynomial of degree $n$. And let $F$ be its splitting field. Show that $[F:K]$ divides $n!$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1763216/let-k-be-a-field-and-fx-in-kx-be-a-polynomial-of-degree-n-and-let-f)

Comment: If $f$ is reducible, write $f = gh$ with the degrees $m, k$ of $g, h$. With your cited question you can bound the degree of the splitting field by $m! k!$ which is strictly smaller then $n!$ if $m, k > 0$.

Comment: The only way to get n! is if splitting off a single root needs a degree $n$ extension (and so on).  But the degree $n$ extension for a root means $f$ is irreducible.  The converse goes wrong in the "(and so on)" part.

Comment: Ah I see, let me try to figure that out, I am also trying to find a counterexample to prove the converse is false. Would $x^4+1$ over Q work hmm

Comment: Yes that would do.

Comment: Ah I just don't quite understand how the degree n extension for a root means f is irreducible though

Comment: For the counterexample, any cyclotomic polynomial of degree greater than 2 will work.

Comment: Could you explain why cyclotomic polynomial works?

Answer (score -1):

Let $f = gh$ with $\deg(g) = m$ and $\deg(h) = k$ be a reducible polynomial. Let $F(a) = K$ and $K(b) = L$ where $a$ is a root of $g$ and $b$ is a root of $h$. We know that $[L :F] = [L : K][K : F] \mid m! k!$, but also that $m!k! < (m + k)!$ (if $m, k > 0$). Hence, $[L : K] < (m + k)! = n!$; which is a contradiction, therefore our original assumption must have been false, meaning that $f$ is irreducible.

Comment: There are too many inaccuracies in this answer.

Comment: For a correct answer see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4772293).